# Warm start with distribute.MirroredStrategy and tf.Estimator

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying run a multi-gpus training using MirroredStartegy and tf.Estimator. The first attempt is to use `tf.train.init_from_chekpoint` in the estimator `model_fn` as follow

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):

    .....

   tf.train.init_from_checkpoint(params['resnet_checkpoint'], {'/': 'resnet50/'})

   ....
```

This throws the following error

```
.../tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/values.py", line 285, in _get_update_device
    "Use DistributionStrategy.update() to modify a MirroredVariable.")
```

The next attempt is to use `tf.estimator.WarmStartSetting`

```
ws = tf.estimator.WarmStartSettings(
        ckpt_to_initialize_from=params['resnet_checkpoint'],
        vars_to_warm_start='resnet50.*',
        var_name_to_prev_var_name=var_name_to_prev_var_name
    )

session_config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)

if FLAGS.num_gpus == 0:
        distribution = tf.contrib.distribute.OneDeviceStrategy('device:CPU:0')
elif FLAGS.num_gpus == 1:
        distribution = tf.contrib.distribute.OneDeviceStrategy('device:GPU:0')
else:
        distribution = tf.contrib.distribute.MirroredStrategy(
            num_gpus=FLAGS.num_gpus
        )
run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(train_distribute=distribution,
                                        session_config=session_config)

estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=model_function,
        params=params,
        config=run_config,
        model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir,
        warm_start_from=ws
    )
```

Again, this throws an error

```
TypeError: var MUST be one of the following: a Variable, list of Variable or PartitionedVariable, but is <class 'tensorflow.contrib.distribute.python.values.MirroredVariable'>
```

Any ideas to fix one of these two approaches ?

Answer (score 0):

Restoring from checkpoints using the 2 mechanisms you tried is unfortunately not yet supported in MirroredStrategy. I've filed a github issue to track this https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19958. Please follow this issue for progress.